# Странное выделение текста RichTextBox WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8

Когда выделяю конец линии в RichTextBox, то выделяется вся линия, можно как то это убрать или исправить?

[image]

[image]

Настройки RichTextBox:

```
Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
Font = rtbFont,
WordWrap = false,
BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
AcceptsTab = true
```

Comment: `AcceptsReturn` настроен?

Comment: @aepot у RichTextBox нет такого параметра, только у TextBox

Comment: Версия .NET какая? Зачем именно вам ричбокс?

Comment: @aepot .NET Framework 4.8, ричбокс т.к делаю блокнот

Comment: А текстбокса почему не хватает?

Comment: @aepot у текстбокса нет некоторых свойств которые я использую (например ZoomFactor)

Comment: он выделяет не всю строку, а слово, в котором находится курсор, ну и все что за ним или передним, смотря куда тянем выделение, а вот как это поменять и возможно ли - хороший вопрос, скорее нет, это нативный контрол и в WordPad он ведет себя так же